# Add folders to zip files

Tags: c, zip

I am following the mentioned link for zipping (creating) zip files. https://www.codeproject.com/articles/7530/zip-utils-clean-elegant-simple-c-win

By using this code I am able to add few random txt files to a newly created zip file, but I now want to be able to add complete folder to it, e.g. **D:\\word\\documents** This documents folder consist of 8 - 10 txt files. Which is why I am trying to add the whole folder to the zip file

Here is the code below:

```
int main ()
{
    HZIP hz = CreateZip("simple1.zip",0);
    ZipAdd(hz,"sample1.txt", "D:\\sample1.txt");
    ZipAdd(hz,"sample2.txt", "D:\\sample2.txt");
    CloseZip(hz);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a workaround for this situation? Or any other library or API that I could use to add folders in zip files?

Comment: In an embedded system (vxWorks) a number of years ago, my team used the zlib (v1.0.4) collection of files. I see this collection still exists, appears to have been updated (to v1.2.8?), and there appears to be a Windows version.  We had few problem zipping multiple files and sub-folders and blocks-of-runtime-data (configuration, etc)  into single zip file.